# Is Picard-Lindelöf Existence Theorem applicable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In our definition of Picard's local existence theorem, we need some *open* $G\subseteq\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$ and then we need to show that $f: G\to\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition locally. Then we may use the existence theorem for all points $(t_0,x_0)\in G$.

We are supposed to check whether Picard is applicable. 
$$y'=2t(1+y(t)) , \quad t\in[0,a], \quad a>0$$
and $y(0)=0$. I showed the Lipschitz condition by using that $y(t)$ is differentiable and therefore must be bounded on the compact set $[0,a]$, is this correct?
Also, is it a problem selecting $G=[0,a]\times \mathbb{R}$? The domain of t is now closed, not open...

Comment: The Lipschitz condition is about the function of $t,y$ itself, i.e. $f(t,y)=2t(1+y)$, which is indeed a Lipschitz function of $y$ when $t$ is held in a bounded interval. Beyond that, the main point is that you can pick some open interval containing $[0,a]$ where the solution exists. (In fact here you have global existence.)

Comment: @Ian so it doesn't matter that $f$ is not defined outside the interval $[0,a]$?

Comment: $f$ should be defined on an open set strictly speaking, but the extension is clear here.

Comment: @Ian The exercise give no further information on the domain of $f$ except $t\in [0,a]$, so you mean that because we can extend $f$ to further $t$ without effort, I can just note that if we extend $f$, we can obviously find an open set around $[0,a]$?